# How to put images out of the screen in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, animation, layout

What I need to do is to put an image off screen.

Here is my situation in Xcode:

[image]

Then I activate a timer which moves downwards the image which slides down. 
How can I reproduce this situation is Android Studio? When I try to put the image off the screen it doesn't let me do it and attaches my image to the margins instead..

Can you help me?

Comment: Its doable. Share your current xml

Comment: put margin top -100dp or something

Comment: android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"

Comment: Thank you @Rah, it works! :)